# Filtering dataframe elements in one step

Tags: apache-spark

I am filtering a dataframe based on one of its long type columns as follow:

```
DataFrame jointsensorData2DoubleDF =//from external source 
jointsensorData2DoubleDF
            .filter(jointsensorData2DoubleDF.col("ts0").isNotNull())
            .filter(jointsensorData2DoubleDF.col("ts0").notEqual(0L))
                .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());
```

I wanted to know if I can do above 3 filters in one filter resulting in an increase speed?

Comment: how can `ts0` be NULL and equal to zero? Are you even getting a dataframe after this?

Comment: the row could be either null or 0 as well..

Comment: I have negated above conditions...

Comment: `jointsensorData2DoubleDF.where(""" ts0 != 0 and ts0 is not null """)`

Comment: @Luckylukee Spark will combine these types of things when executing, so you shouldn't get any speed difference when running.

Comment: Key word: Whole stage Codegen + Catalyst Optimizer :)

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know if I can do above 3 filters in one filter resulting

Rewriting conditions in a single step won't affect the execution plan:

```
scala> Seq[java.lang.Long]().toDF("t0").filter($"t0".isNotNull).filter($"t0" =!= 0).explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter NOT ('t0 = 0)
+- Filter isnotnull(t0#107L)
   +- Project [value#105L AS t0#107L]
      +- LocalRelation <empty>, [value#105L]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
t0: bigint
Filter NOT (t0#107L = cast(0 as bigint))
+- Filter isnotnull(t0#107L)
   +- Project [value#105L AS t0#107L]
      +- LocalRelation <empty>, [value#105L]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation <empty>, [t0#107L]

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan <empty>, [t0#107L]
```

Conjunction:

```
scala> Seq[java.lang.Long]().toDF("t0").filter($"t0".isNotNull && $"t0" =!= 0).explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter (isnotnull('t0) && NOT ('t0 = 0))
+- Project [value#114L AS t0#116L]
   +- LocalRelation <empty>, [value#114L]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
t0: bigint
Filter (isnotnull(t0#116L) && NOT (t0#116L = cast(0 as bigint)))
+- Project [value#114L AS t0#116L]
   +- LocalRelation <empty>, [value#114L]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation <empty>, [t0#116L]

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan <empty>, [t0#116L]
```